# Translate or customize Command Palette in the monaco-editor browser version

Tags: javascript, webpack, monaco-editor

How can I change or translate to the end the items in right button mouse menu?
How can I customize items in Command Palette in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot customize either the command pallet nor the context menu. The only way to show own content instead is to disable both and show own popups.